# Configuring rabbitmq with spring4 stomp and socksjs application

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, sockjs, spring-4

I am having issue with spring 4+Stomp+socks js app. It was working fine with simple message broker but when switch to rabbitmq it is not working and could not solve it with the answer mentioned at 
[Configure External Broker(RabbitMQ) In Spring4+STOMP+SockJS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557473/configure-external-brokerrabbitmq-in-spring4stompsockjs-application/26437405#26437405)

My code is:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/hello">
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:stomp-broker-relay prefix="/topic" system-login="guest" system-passcode="guest" client-login="guest"
                                  client-passcode="guest" relay-host="localhost" relay-port="15672"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Controller:

```
    @Controller
public class StompController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greetUser(User user) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + user.getName() + "!");
    }



}
```

Js:

```
function connect() {
            var socket = new SockJS('/hello');
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
            stompClient.connect('guest','guest', function(frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function(greeting){
                    showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
                });
            });
        }
```

While connecting it is saying:

> SEVERE [clientInboundChannel-1] org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal **Message broker is not active.** Ignoring: [Payload byte[0]][Headers={stompCommand=CONNECT, stompCredentials=[PROTECTED], nativeHeaders={heart-beat=[10000,10000], passcode=[PROTECTED], login=[guest], accept-version=[1.1,1.0]}, simpMessageType=CONNECT, simpSessionAttributes={}, simpSessionId=ih_04mxa, id=d36fc1c1-e00c-fb48-51af-c526e3018e20, timestamp=1413617272621}]

I have even enabled stomp plugin in rabbit mq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### STOMP port

I think Spring can't connect to your RabbitMQ instance because you're pointing it to port 15672, which I think must be the default port for the web UI or something else. [The default port for the STOMP connector with rabbitMQ is 61613](http://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) (and indeed this is [the default value chosen by Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/97596fb9f6b6052f60c316202dde8646271b008c/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.java#L34)). Could you try with that one?

### Access Control

Also, you should definitely think about your access control configuration, [as the guest user won't work remotely](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).

Comment: It seems to me that for the front-end client the port should be 15674