# SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend with RabbitMQ works very slow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I'm using spring STOMP over Websocket with RabbitMQ. All works fine but simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend works very slow, call can take 2-10 seconds (synchronously, block thread). What can be a reason??

RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend take < 1s, but I need stomp over websocket..

**UPDATE**

I try to use ActiveMQ and gets the same result. convertAndSend take 2-10 seconds

ActiveMQ have default configuration.

Web socket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue", "/exchange");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/topic", "/queue"); // prefix in client queries
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/board").withSockJS()
    }

    @Override
    void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(8 * 1024);
    }
}
```

Comment: which spring version are you using? could you give an example of a message before/after conversion?

Comment: Too much to ask but could you attempt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55016259/5051731) question of mine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem resolved. Its bug in io.projectreactor library version 2.0.4.RELEASE. I change to 2.0.8.RELEASE and its fixed problem. Sending message now take ~50ms.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```