# Spring Websocket and 404 status on connection

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

In a working Spring MVC 4.0.2 project running under Tomcat 7.0.50, I'm trying to implement Spring Websocket with simple broker and sockjs stomp endpoint, following the [official reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket). So, in the contextConfigLocation (DistpacherServlet property) I've add a value "websocket-config.xml" which contains:

```
>     <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app" >
>           <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/monitor">
>             <websocket:sockjs />
>           </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
>           <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic"/>
>     </websocket:message-broker>
```

In eclipse console (catalina log) when I start Tomcat, appear the rows

> - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientInboundChannelExecutor'
> - Initializing ExecutorService  'clientOutboundChannelExecutor'
> - Initializing ExecutorService  'messageBrokerSockJsScheduler'
> - Mapped URL path [/monitor/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler]

In the jsp page I put the code

> . . . .
>      var socket = new SockJS("monitor");
>      var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
>      . . . .

Unfortunately when I load the jsp page from Chrome (v32), I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> > http ://localhost:8080/(ProjectName)/monitor/info

Obviously I'm doing this test locally, then all other webapp resources are reachable at http ://localhost/(ProjectName) correctly.

What's wrong?

**** Update 20 Feb 2014
I've tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868232/how-to-use-tomcat-8-in-eclipse) resolved stack question, which suggests to use Tomcat8 for Spring Websocket, unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any log output on the server side as a result of the request to /monitor/info? How is the DispatcherServlet itself mapped? I would expect to "/" from what you have above.

The SockJS endpoint is basically a URL mapped in Spring MVC (with a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping) so try other Spring MVC mapped controller methods. And turn up logging, could there be a filter or something else returning the 404?

Comment: WONDERFUL! :)) I've spent so much time trying to fix this problem and you solved it in a while. My mistake is the usage of Dispatcher url-pattern "*.do", so the Servlet doesn't catch websocket client request. I changed it in "/", (but I had to add others fake url pattern for resource files, as suggested by @Gofier [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169266/where-to-place-images-css-in-spring-mvc-app) and it worked! 
I love you :)
Many thanks

Comment: Glad it's working now :) Keep in mind that for serving resource files we also have a resource handling mechanism. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer a little?  Are you saying the dispatcher servlet needs to also handle the requests for the SockJS endpoint?

Comment: Paul, yes the SockJS endpoint is an HTTP endpoint mapped with and served by Spring MVC. See SockJsHttpRequestHandler.

Comment: Hi there! I'm having the same issue, but unfortunately haven't used websockets for long and am wondering what you mean by changing things in "/"? Could you possibly walk me through what you had to do to fix the issue?

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev The endpoint is a static one like         registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/");
or is it a servlet mappoing to add in  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
  return new String[] { "/" };
 } ?

Comment: I also get a 404 on the ws://localhost:8080/nitro-project-rest/app/bts request with a mapping as: Mapped URL path [/app/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

Comment: @Theo In my case if I am not using STOMP and I am trying to connect using this url ws://localhost:8443/MyApp/call it doesn't work I get  404 for this, however I see another call fired from the page with http://localhost:8080/MyApp/call but the ws thing doesn't work, I do get and output "NoMapping found" and aslo in browser about: failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev Hello sir, I have subscription mapping client side side code which subscribe to  Channel, on first load page in `<iFrame>` I subscribed to channel successfully (with conditional code on first page load), if I refresh page I lost subscribed channel and get error **Whoops! Lost connection to <myurl>**

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggle with this issue this might helps.
I had following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> 
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
 <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name> 
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>
```

And had 404 response for this url:
http ://localhost:8080/(ProjectName)/monitor

But this one works like charm:
http ://localhost:8080/(ProjectName)/rest/monitor

Cheers!