# Convert standalone application to war

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, spring-boot

Trying this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/). Could run it as in example, but can not convert it to war file using web.xml and spring xml config files.
[Here is what I did](https://github.com/KaPaHgaIII/WSTest), but it is not working.
When I press "connect" I got

> GET _http://localhost:8080/hello/info 404 (Not Found)

in browser console and

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello/info] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

in tomcat log

**UPDATE:**
Page _http://localhost:8080/hello says "Welcome to SockJS!"

### UPDATE 2

Ok, I found this question:
[Spring Websocket and 404 status on connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883033/spring-websocket-and-404-status-on-connection)
It says that servlet-mapping should be "/". And tells how to get acces to index.html (in comment). I tried and it works... Now I have this browser console output:

> Opening Web Socket...
>   stomp.js:130 Web Socket Opened...
>   stomp.js:130 >>> CONNECT
>   accept-version:1.1,1.0
>   heart-beat:10000,10000
>   Whoops! Lost connection to undefined

And tomcat log:

> SEVERE: Broken data received. Terminating WebSocket connection
>   abruptly java.lang.IllegalStateException: A SockJsMessageCodec is
>   required but not available: Add Jackson 2 to the classpath, or
>   configure a custom SockJsMessageCodec.

### UPDATE 3

adding Jaskson 2 dependensy to pom.xml (important version 2.1.0 or above) solved problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It works, but returns 7 answers to one request...

### FINAIL UPDATE

I had two configurations: in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and in java code.
Both of them worked, so requests and answers intersects and multiplies.
Final version can be found in [github](https://github.com/KaPaHgaIII/WSTest), commit 2b2e605b39d8acfc8913b836dadb1ab2c19b4795

Comment: I dont see any request mapping to /hello/info... is the /hello working ?

Comment: @balajikrishnan, it says "Welcome to SockJS!"

Comment: so its just a missing request mapping.. include a @RequestMapping for the /hello/info and you should be fine