# How to allow websocket|sockjs path 'socket.do/info' when Spring MVC url-pattern mapping is "*.do"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I want to open a websocket connection in my Spring MVC apllication, using SockJS,STOMP. The problem I have is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883033/spring-websocket-and-404-status-on-connection/). but answer will not work for me. I have followed tutorials from  [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/).
As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883033/spring-websocket-and-404-status-on-connection/) my app is returning a 404 to the browser when calling the webapp/socket.do mapping. javascript code is as below :

```
    socket = new SockJS('webapp/socket.do');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {...
```

My servlet mapping in web.xml file is as below:

```
    `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>`
```

Now I tried changing url mapping from "*.do" to "/" and using other resource url patterns as suggested [here by @Gofier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169266/where-to-place-images-css-in-spring-mvc-app) this ("/")made a connection open but not render some resources properly.(webpages dont load properly).

Is there any way I can still use "*.do" and allow a websocket connection with "/info" at the same time ?? Please suggest any possible ways to fix this issue. Thanks.

***Update***: Showing controller code and config file

```
@Configuration 
@EnableScheduling 
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.package") 
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker 
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket.do").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/", "/topic/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
 @MessageMapping("/hello")
 @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
 public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
     Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
     return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
 }
```

Comment: can you show your controller code here

Comment: Updated my controller code

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatch-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this?